# Import Tables From Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Sorry if this is dumb question. I want to know if/how to import tables from one database to another using the mysql console/command line. I would love to speed up my workflow with Something like this

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
IMPORT tables into dbname
```

I have been creating a lot of databases locally using wamp and would like to easily create my database and import some WordPress tables using the command line. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CREATE TABLE targetdb.tablename SELECT * FROM sourcedb.tablename`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) to copy the table structure and its content from one database to another database.

Note that auto increment and indizes are not preserved, but can be added to the `CREATE TABLE` statement explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can export one database and then can import that to another database.

**mysqldump --host=hostip --user=username --password=password --database databasename > dump.sql
mysql --host=hostip --user=username --password=password databasename < dump.sql**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with the use of the mysqldump tool (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) and command line mysql usage

```
> mysqldump --no-create-db [DB name] > /path/to/file.sql
> mysql -h [hostname] -u [username] -p[password] [new db name] < /path/to/file.sql
```

Note here the use of the `--no-create-db` option, which will remove the CREATE DATABASE part of the SQL, allowing you to create the DB with new name.